# Viability of node.js serve video file with stream

Tags: node.js, video-streaming

I was wondering about how well it would work to stream large video files on a server that already handles .html. I assume that this is blocking each time the content is served.

Does anyone have experience with this? Or any general recommendations?

Comment: It works fine.  The streaming of content from disk isn't blocking.  Not sure why you'd want to do this at the application layer though.  You'll usually find that it's cheaper to serve your video from a CDN.

Comment: I have no money to spend on this. It is for a personal internal project. :D

Comment: In any case, is there a reason why you don't want to just use a normal web server like Nginx?

Comment: I saw this recently: https://github.com/daspinola/video-stream-sample/blob/master/server.js#L12 and tried it out and it seems to work well. I have generated pdfs on the fly and then sent them streaming before to avoid blocking other requests before, but I was unsure about how that would work with a larger file.

Comment: There should be no reason for that code.  Express Static already handles ranged requests.